# ladvd and libpcap installation?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cross-platform, libpcap, powerpc

I was trying to install ladvd package on PowerPc, & while using ./configure command I faced below error

```
 checking pcap.h usability... yes
 checking pcap.h presence... yes
 checking for pcap.h... yes
 checking for pcap_compile in -lpcap... no
 configure: error: libpcap is required
```

for that i installed lipcap successfully by using ./configure, make and make install.

But still after that I am getting the same error.
Is there any other way to solve the above error and make it work.

Comment: Check the `config.log` file for details of the failure, and post the relevant parts of that here for others to take a look at.

Comment: Also, can you post the full `./configure` invocation?